Matlab object arrays' method call equivalent in Python
Matlab has object arrays, Python has lists or tuples.
Calling a method of a class on an object array of objects of that class, is easy in Matlab:
A = [Class1(1), Class1(2)];

B = A.toClass2();

see "Invoking Methods on an Object Array" here
In Python, this would not be 1 to 1 transferable because on the second line, the interpreter would look for the method toClass2() in the List class, which it will not find (->error).
I found out that this can be solved from outside that method's definition, on the user side, by calling it in a for loop, list comprehension, map of a function or lambda function, or even using numpy.vectorize(), see this.
Each of these solutions imply heavier syntax on the user side, and one thing still misses; what if I want the method Class1.toClass2() can decide for itself how to treat a list of multiple objects received as input.
For instance a method Class1.Sum() would logically sum all elements on which it is applied and return a single object, whereas another doing some transformation like Class1.toClass2() might as well return an array of new objects.
Alternatively, one can make the method toClass2() also accept a List as self input, and call it explicitly on the second line on the list A using:
B = Class1.toClass2(A) 

This allows methods choosing how to treat List inputs, but generates slightly heavier syntax on the user's side.
Does anyone see another solution ?
Maybe there is one using method decorators, class decorators, or even subclassing the List class ..
Else more generally, how to adapt this OOP software architecture design thinking from Matlab arrays to Python's universe ?

There are many solutions for your immediate problem, but in general you cannot translate syntax 1-to-1 from one language to another. Each language has its own syntax and its own peculiarities.
In MATLAB, A.toClass2() and toClass2(A) both call the same function. The second syntax you can directly translate to Python by writing a free function (i.e. not a class method) that does something different depending on the type of the input.
A different alternative is to not create lists of your object in Python, but to have an object contain a list with the data (or create a class that contains a list of your objects). Then you can customize methods working on that object.

Hey Cris,
Thanks for your reply !
I really like your second idea, I'll try this out.
Maybe another possibility could be to create my own subclass of the python list or tuple, which is transparent to method calls (transmitts unknown method calls to the list or tuple's elements' instances like in Matlab).
I could achiege this using a decorator of some sort, and use that one instead of the default python list or tuple in my code...
Like you said, there are many variants.
Thanks again !
